# Finding Intersection of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

My attempt:

After substituting variables I got basis of V = { (1,0,0,0),(0,-1,1,0),(0,-1,0,1)} and W = {(-1,1,0,0),(0,0,4,1).

These are also the basis of these subspaces so dim(V) = 3 and dim(W) = 2

For V+W,

Found the reduced row echelon form with [v1 v2 v3 w1 w2], had 4 pivots, i.e. v1,v2,v3,w1 -> which implies these are the basis for V+W and dim(V+W) = 4.

Now I am stuck at the part of finding it for the intersection, I've been trying to do it with the reduced row echelon form but I get a matrix in which the c=4d condition is not satisfied. How do I go about solving it with row-reduced echelon form ?

[image]

This is the row reduced form. In some books it is written that we take the non pivotal as the vector for intersection but w2 is 0,0,4,1 which does not satisfy all equations.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: If $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are the basis vectors for $V$ and $w_1,w_2$ are the basis vectors for $W$, you want to know when there is a *nontrivial* solution of
$$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3 = c_4w_1+c_5w_2.$$
So one of the matrices you considered already will tell you the answer, if you think about it correctly.

Comment: It gives me a non-trivial solution but does not satisfy the c=4d condition

Comment: No, the values of the $c_i$ aren't the answer here.

Comment: No, I meant the initial question condition of W having c=4d, not c1,c2 and so on

Comment: Your basis vectors go in the columns, so I don't understand what you’re talking about.

Comment: Once I get the row reduced echelon form, the infinite based solution that I get with x5 as t does not satisfy the initial W and V conditions given in the q such as c=4d, b+c+d = 0

Comment: That's exactly my point. You’re solving for the $c$’s. These are not the vectors in the subspace. Keep going. How do we find vectors in $V\cap W$?

Comment: I understood your point, I found the row-reduced matrix for this and I got all variables represented by the last one, (which should be the case cuz V intersection W dimension should be 1) but the basis I am getting is (-5,-4,-1,5), here it does not satisfy c=4d from W

Comment: You continue to ignore what I've said. You start with a $4\times 5$ matrix $A$, whose columns are the $v$'s and $w$'s. The solutions of $Ax=0$ will be vectors in $\Bbb R^5$, not vectors in $\Bbb R^4$. A basis for this solution space is the vector $(5,4,1,5,-1)$ in $\Bbb R^5$. What does this tell us?

Comment: I'm a tad bit confused, if we get a solution of Ax=0, it means there will be infinite solutions as a solution other than the trivial one exists, which means we can write the other variables in terms of the free variable

Comment: Does this imply that 5v1 + 4v2 + 1v3 = w2 - 5w1 which is the intersection ?

Comment: Yes, this is precisely correct! (Of course, Lorenzo's answer gives you the easiest approach to this particular problem, since you have equations for the subspaces. But your approach will work if you're given vectors spanning them.)

Answer (score 0):

The intersection is defined by the conditions $b + c + d = 0, a + b = 0, c = 4d$, since this is the union of the conditions defining $V$ and $W$. (In general, $\ker(A) \cap \ker(B) = \ker ( A \cup B)$, where by $A \cup B$ I mean that matrix obtained by stacking $A$ on top of $B$.)

Put these in a matrix, and compute the kernel.